# Julia: fastest way to generate a single random number from a non-standard normal distribution?

Tags: random, julia

Each sample in my simulation should come from a normal distribution with a mean which comes from a pre-defined list (i.e. I sample only once from each distribution because the mean changes for each sample). Do I need to generate a distribution each time and then draw from it, as in:

```
using Random, Distributions

for i in 1:n
    d1 = Normal(means[i], s)
    sample[i] = rand(d1, 1)
end
```

or is there something faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sample from the standard normal distribution, and translate and scale to get your desired mean/variance i.e.

```
sample .= randn(n) .* s .+ means
```

(note: much more efficient to sample a vector of normal variables, than sampling one at a time)